# Bundling MySQL server installer with a Java project

Tags: java, mysql, windows-installer

I just finished a Java project that uses a MySQL database.
I need to generate a Windows installer that creates a folder for the project in "Program Files", automatic installs MySQL Server Essential and the JRE to run the project.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a zip file at compile time using assemblies:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>
                        src/main/assemblies/my-assembly.xml
                    </descriptor>
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

You could use that to bundle mysql together with your application. Along with mysql, you could bundle together a batch script that installs mysql and the JRE where you want it. Or you could handle the install programmatically within your application if the JRE already exists in the target system.